# setWidth100 does not work with smartgwt Label

Tags: java, smartgwt

SmartGWT generally fails to stand up to it's name when comes to simple layouts.

I want a simple label that expands to fit in the parent `VLayout`s width.

```
    VLayout contentDownloadLink = new VLayout();


    Label downloadHeader = new Label("<center><b>Export dokončen</b></center><br />Stahování začne automaticky.");
    downloadHeader.setBorder("1px solid red");
    downloadHeader.setWidth100();

    contentDownloadLink.addMember(downloadHeader);
    contentDownloadLink.setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);         
    contentDownloadLink.setAlign(VerticalAlignment.CENTER); 
    contentDownloadLink.setAutoWidth();
    contentDownloadLink.setMinWidth(350);
    contentDownloadLink.setBorder("1px solid black");
```

This is the result:

[image]

Clearly the width is not 100%. Is there a workaround for that?